# Trying to create config cmake file, but it is generated wrong

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, qt6

I've written a library and I want to package it to be used just like any other library I install on Ubuntu. It worked but I'm getting `find_package(mentorsms REQUIRED)` **cmake error** in my application I want to use the library with. The error points to my installed `mentorsmsConfig.cmake` file, but it looks like it was generated wrong. The error is:

> /usr/lib/mentorsms/cmake/mentorsmsConfig.cmake:8: error:
> configure_file Problem configuring file CMakeLists.txt:18
> (find_package)

This is my **dir tree** with some key files:

```
mentorsms
--mentorsmslib-1.0
----debian
------control
------rules
----build
------debugrelease
--------Makefile
--------mentorsmsConfig.cmake
----src
------CMakeLists.txt
------cmake
--------mentorsmsConfig.cmake.in
```

**mentorsmsConfig.cmake.in**:

```
set(PACKAGE_NAME "@PACKAGE_NAME@")
set(PACKAGE_VERSION "@PACKAGE_VERSION@")
set(PACKAGE_STRING "${PACKAGE_NAME} ${PACKAGE_VERSION}")
set(PACKAGE_TARNAME "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}")
set(PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "@PACKAGE_BUGREPORT@")
set(PACKAGE_URL "@PACKAGE_URL@")

configure_file(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/mentorsmsConfig.cmake.in"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mentorsmsConfig.cmake"
  @ONLY@
)
```

**mentorsmsConfig.cmake**:

```
set(PACKAGE_NAME "")
set(PACKAGE_VERSION "")
set(PACKAGE_STRING "${PACKAGE_NAME} ${PACKAGE_VERSION}")
set(PACKAGE_TARNAME "${PACKAGE_NAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}")
set(PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "")
set(PACKAGE_URL "")

configure_file(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/mentorsmsConfig.cmake.in"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mentorsmsConfig.cmake"
  
)
```

So, yeah... I don't care much about the empty strings, my `CMakeLists.txt` is basically default for a **Qt shared library** project, **debuild** does all that for the package I believe (or should I really copy-paste name, version, url and all that?). But the `config_file` section should be replaced with something, no?

My **rules** file is a little lengthy, as this is the first time I was packaging anything and just did it manually almost... but three `cmake` commands are what should generate the config file, something wrong with them?

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@
    
override_dh_auto_clean:
    rm -fr $$(pwd)/build/debugrelease/* ; \
    rm -fr $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/* ; \
    rm -fr $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib-dev/* ; \
    rm -fr $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib-src/*
    
override_dh_auto_configure:
    cmake -H$$(pwd)/src -B$$(pwd)/build/debugrelease -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=mentorsms

override_dh_auto_build:
    cmake --build $$(pwd)/build/debugrelease --target all
    
override_dh_auto_install:
    mkdir -p $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib/mentorsms ; \
    cmake --install $$(pwd)/build/debugrelease --config RelWithDebInfo --prefix $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib ; \
    mv $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib/mentorsms/libmentorsms.so $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib/mentorsms/libmentorsms.so.1.0 ; \
    ln -s $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib/mentorsms/libmentorsms.so.1.0 $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib/mentorsms/libmentorsms.so.1 ; \
    ln -s $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib/mentorsms/libmentorsms.so.1.0 $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib/usr/lib/mentorsms/libmentorsms.so ; \
    mkdir -p $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib-dev/usr/include/mentorsms ; \
    mkdir -p $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib-src/usr/src/mentorsms ; \
    find $$(pwd)/src -name "*.h" -type f -exec cp {} $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib-dev/usr/include/mentorsms \; ; \
    cp -R $$(pwd)/src $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib-src/usr/src/mentorsms ; \
    rm -f -- $$(pwd)/debian/mentorsmslib-src/usr/src/mentorsms/CMakeLists.txt.user
    
override_dh_installudev:
    dh_installudev --name=serial --priority=99 ; \
    dh_installudev --name=hid --priority=99
```

Comment: "I'm getting `find_package(mentorsms REQUIRED)` cmake error in my application" - What exact error do you get? Please, add **exact error message** to the question post. In the current form it is unclear what is your problem.

Comment: Your `mentorsmsConfig.cmake.in` looks weird. Read the CMake docs for the `CMakePackageConfigHelpers` module. Also, why not use CMake/CPack to produce DEB (or whatever other) package (instead of having `rules` and all that stuff)?

Comment: Please, do not use *blockquote* formatting for error messages: this formatting doesn't preserve newlines, which are important for error messages in most cases. E.g. in the given case different call trace entries should be located on different lines in the error message. Instead, format error messages as **code**.